# Adding a ScrollView breaks my CanvasView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a CanvasView in my fragment layout that lets me draw to the screen. However, when add a ScrollingView to the layout, the fragments are able to scroll but I can no longer draw. Does anyone know why this is? The canvas is inside a framelayout which is inside the scrollview. If it's unclear what I mean, essentially I cannot draw on my canvas if there is also a scrollview in the same spot.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.brettrosen.atls.fragments.PrimarySurvey">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.brettrosen.atls.canvas.CanvasView
        android:id="@+id/canvas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/prearrival_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/prearrival_1"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/prearrival_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/prearrival_2"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/prearrival_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/prearrival_3"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:hint="kg"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/prearrival_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/prearrival_4"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/prearrival_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/prearrival_5"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/prearrival_6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/prearrival_6"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/prearrival_7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/prearrival_7"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/prearrival_8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/prearrival_8"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="For Attending level activations:"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/prearrival_9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/prearrival_9"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/prearrival_10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/prearrival_10"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/prearrival_11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/prearrival_11"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/prearrival_12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/prearrival_12"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:id="@+id/drawToggle"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="onDrawClicked"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: I tried moving my ScrollView inside my FrameLayout (underneath canvas) but it still doesn't work.

CanvasView.java onDraw()

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Before "drawPath"
    canvas.drawColor(this.baseColor);

    if (this.bitmap != null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(this.bitmap, 0F, 0F, new Paint());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this.historyPointer; i++) {
        Path path   = this.pathLists.get(i);
        Paint paint = this.paintLists.get(i);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    this.drawText(canvas);

    this.canvas = canvas;
}
```

Comment: What's your onDraw method ? Try to set fixed height of canvas.

Comment: @eurosecom I'm using the CanvasView API, I edited my question with their onDraw()

Answer (score 0):

With your layout first checkbox overlap canvas. Try to change layout. I see Canvas and I can scroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.brettrosen.atls.fragments.PrimarySurvey">

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.zzztest2.CanvasView
    android:id="@+id/canvas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/prearrival_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cc1"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"


...
..
```

Comment: @erosecom Just got back to this issue, seems like this isn't working either. Only lets me draw outside of the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to add a canvas within a scrollview, but realised there is a much better way.

Rather use the canvas functions:
canvas.translate(offsetx,offsety) {for scrolling}
and
canvas.scale(scalexFactor,scaleyFactor) {for pinch zoom}

at the beginning of your canvas Draw() function

These allow you to emulate a zoomable scrollview, and works much faster.

Obviously, your (x,y) input values in translate and scale will be determined by you by using
1) your touch event functions (touch down, touch drag, touch up) {for scrolling}
2) a pinchgesture listener {for scaling/zooming}